# WebAPI error: When POST method is created - Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I keep getting this error when I try to have a POST method with 2 "Get" methods

my WebAPI:

```
        [ResponseType(typeof(Organization))]
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        [System.Web.Http.ActionName("CreateOrganization")]
        public IHttpActionResult CreateOrganization(Organization org)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            helper.InsertOrganization(org); 

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = org.Id }, org);
        }

        //GET: api/Products/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Organization))]
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
        [System.Web.Http.ActionName("FindBy")]
        public IHttpActionResult FindBy(int id)
        {
            Organization org = helper.QueryOnOrganizationBy(id);
            if (org == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(org);
        }

        [ResponseType(typeof(Organization))]
        [System.Web.Http.ActionName("All")]
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult All()
        {    
            List<Organization> orgList = helper.QueryAllOnOrganization(); 

            if (orgList == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(orgList);
          }
```

ERROR:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nCreateOrganization on type ProductReviews.Controllers.OrganizationsController\r\nAll on type ProductReviews.Controllers.OrganizationsController\r\nQueryAllOnTable on type ProductReviews.Controllers.OrganizationsController\r\nOpenConn on type ProductReviews.Controllers.OrganizationsController\r\nCloseConn on type ProductReviews.Controllers.OrganizationsController",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

WEB API Route:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            //To produce JSON format add this line of code
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `[ActionName]` attributes on your controller actions, then your route template needs to include `{action}`:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

The default template `"api/{controller}/{id}"` assumes that you will only use the HTTP method (e.g., GET or POST) and optional `id` to distinguish between actions.

Also, in Web API, you should use the `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` attributes from the `System.Web.Http` namespace, not `System.Web.Mvc`.

Comment: What is the best practice? I have seen on asp.net blog uses the action name so I am not sure should I use that on every method, what do you think

Comment: I don't think there's a best practice that everyone agrees upon. Some people use action names (which is the default style in ASP.NET MVC). Other people use the `[Route]` attribute instead of `[ActionName]` to construct more RESTful URLs. See [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for more info.

Comment: if I add the `/{action}` then the both get methods are not working.

Comment: i have changed  `Http.Verb` to using System.Web.Http, thanks for catching that.

Comment: If you change the route template to `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`, then you also need to update the URLs in your AJAX calls and insert the action name. For example, the URL for your All action would be `/api/Organizations/All` instead of `/api/Organizations`.

Comment: i am getting 404 error after adding the `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` and my uri looks like this `http://localhost:53811/api/organizations` and also i have tried like this `http://localhost:53811/api/organizations/1` and if i removed the {action} then the get methods works except the post as i have posted my original question, is there a way you can show me  sample working?

Comment: Please review my previous comment carefully. If you don't want to change your URLs, then you should use the `[Route]` attribute instead of `[ActionName]`. See the linked article in my first comment.